# Inheriting url extension from iframe child

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I have a webpage that loads an iframe full-screen and I would like the parent page to have a dynamic url so when you click the child and navigate to [www.childpage.com/page1](http://www.childpage.com/page1), the visible parent url changes to [www.parentpage.com/page1](http://www.parentpage.com/page1).  I would also like [www.parentpage.com/page1](http://www.parentpage.com/page1) to be a hard-link so going directly to that url loads the iframe as [www.childpage.com/page1](http://www.childpage.com/page1).

I know this is possible but I've found most of the answers thus far either confusing or incomplete.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: This is only possible if you control `childpage.com` and can manipulate the links there. This seems hardly practical though, and comes with many many obstacles - for example, posting forms will no longer work. Why not just re-map the domains and call it a day?